# Is there a way to avoid geometry nodes calculating if the object is hidden via the Outliner

Tags: 3d-view, geometry-nodes, geometry, visibility

I observed that when the container geometry for a geometry node tree is hidden with the eye icon in the outliner, the tree is still evaluated.

Is there a way to avoid that? I would have expected that it does it out of the box, but it does not. I could also imagine to implement something with the switch node. But how would I access the visibility in the node tree.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello ! I think you are talking about the viewport visibility, which is just a visual feedback change. All the objects are still there and evaluated. What you want is to disable the object, with the monitor icon insteaf of the eye icon

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for your response. I did not refer to the switching in the modifier stack, i.e. monitor or eye icon, but to the visibility in the Outliner, where you can disable the visibility in viewport (eye) or render visibility (camera). It would be neat to hide an element in the viewport and its calculation would stop as well. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Yeah by default the monitor icon is not displayed in the outliner. you can enable it by clicking on the sieve icon in the top right of the outliner and activating the monitor icon there. Alternatively you can disable objects by selecting one of them > Object properties > Visibility panel > Show in Viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your item is in a collection that is unticked (excluded from viewlayer) it is also not evaluated - I find this a quick way to be able to turn large chunks of a scene off from a processing.

Comment: I agree. Thank you that helped a lot. Boosting the fps up again to quickly check if the animation plays out nicely.